# How can I force a float casting on elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index elasticsearch with a mapping:

```
{
  "book": {
    "mappings": {
      "educational": {
        "properties": {
          "price": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I can index a document with instead of a float, a string:

```
{
  "title": "Test",
  "price": "120.99"
}
```

The value of price will be presented as a string when I will retrieve this document later, despite the fact that the mapping say it should be a float.

I know that the price will still be indexed as a float despite the fact that it is presented as a string but is there a way to force a casting of the field into a float to have a better coherence in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

internally the field will be stored as a float, when [coercing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/coerce.html) is used. However the original document will not be changed, which means the original JSON will still contain the field as a string.

You could use a [convert processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/convert-processor.html) in a pipeline to change the string to a float before the document is being indexed.